# Deserializing Json array of "oneOf" structures

Tags: json, go

I have JSON documents that contain an array where each item is either a string or a map representing an object.

```
{"oneOfArray": ["str1", "str2", {"SomeStruct": "value3"}, "str4", {"SomeStruct": "value5"} ]}
```

How can I create Go classes that represent this kind of structure and provide deserialization via the `json` package?

Answer (score 1):

There is no generic support in Go (yet), so you cannot create an array that would represent the different types of values coming from your JSON.

One way is use a slice of type `[]interface{}`, and the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package will choose types itself to unmarshal into, which will be `map[string]interface{}` for JSON objects.

You may model the outer object with this type:

```
type Obj struct {
    OneOfArray []interface{} `json:"oneOfArray"`
}
```

Example unmarshaling your input:

```
src := `{"oneOfArray": ["str1", "str2", {"SomeStruct": "value3"}, "str4", {"SomeStruct": "value5"} ]}`

var obj Obj

if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &obj); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(obj)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uVOeq9Vt1Co)):

```
{[str1 str2 map[SomeStruct:value3] str4 map[SomeStruct:value5]]}
```